# JMeter: Load testing of a HTTP POST followed by a HTTP GET

Tags: java, junit, jmeter, load-testing

I am evaluating performance of my transport library and it will be helpful if I get suggestions on the following:

I use a Junit sampler to perform the following:

HTTP POST test: I send a HTTP POST request: This will cause a DB write. I have to evaluate all the parameters (throughput, avg. response time) holistically for POST + DB_WRITE operation. As response to this POST request, I get a unique id. So if I send 1000 successful POST requests, I will have 1000 unique ids.

Now my question is how can I use these unique ids for my next test case, perform a HTTP GET on each of created unique ids.

I can parse the HTTP POST response and write the unique id into a file and try using that file for my HTTP GET test. But the problem is if I create a thread group of 10 different threads, there will be issues of synchronization on file writing.

Is there any PostProcessor I can use to record results in filesystem?

Answer (score 3):

As for me looks like you can avoid usage of file to store and then read generated id's.

Logic is the following:

1. execute your POST request;
2. parse response returned from POST - using Regular Expression Extractor or any other [post-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) attached to the request - to extract your ID;
3. store extracted ID in user-unique / thread-unique variable - in the same post-processor;

   how to do this for Regular Expression Extractor see below: `${__javaScript('${username}'+'UnicID')}` generates unique variable for each user/thread, to avoid interference in multi-user cases;

   seems that can also use [threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function instead of ${username} variable;
4. if POST request completed successfully, ID extracted and stored in variable - execute your GET request were extracted ID is used as param;

   use `${__V(${username}UnicID)}` construction to get back previously saved ID.

You may add also add [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) to POST request sampler - to monitor generated variables and their values.

Seems that's all.

`Thread Group
Number of Threads = X
Loop Count = N
    . . .
    HTTP Request POST
        checkingReturnCode  // Response Assertion
        extractUniqueID     // Regular Expression Extractor (e.g.)
            Reference Name = ${__javaScript('${username}'+'UnicID')}
            Regular Expression = ...
            Template = $1$
            Match No. = 1
            Default Value = NOTFOUND
    IF Controller           // execute GET only if POST was successful
    Condition = ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}  // you may change this to verify that variable with extracted ID is not empty
        HTTP Request GET
        param = ${__V(${username}UnicID)}
    . . .`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. But one more question, if I understand what you say correctly, a single test would do a HTTP POST and then immediately a HTTP GET, right? But I want to measure a bunch of POST and a bunch of GETs separately or did I understand what you said incorrectly?

Comment: @ Prasanna. All the statistics and characteristics will be measured for executed POST and GET requests irrespectively you run they one-by-one in the same Thread Group or in different Thread Groups consequently or even in different jmx-files. So if you attach listeners to your script to get requests characteristics you will see measurement results separately for POST and for GET even if they are executed in the same Thread Group one-by-one, as in example above.

Comment: In this case, if you necessarily wants divide POST and GET requests execution you could use the same mechanism as above but with 2 Thread Groups: in the 1st POST will be executed and ID extracted and stored in variable, in the 2nd - GET send with ID as param.

The only point is that in case of 2 Thread Groups you possibly have to additionaly store extracted ID in property instead of variable and then read value from property - to store values between Thread Groups.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any problems with synchronization (they are resolved by file system). In every thread (which is POST-ing) you should open your file for writing and append a new line to it. Again, don't worry about synchronization, OS will take care of it.